# How to show User control on Dotnetnuke Module Page?

Tags: c#, .net, dotnetnuke

I have Created Module and Create One User Control in the Module.

Now, How can I Add This User Control on a Page ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If am not sure how you have created module since you are not stating dnn version, you can review [this example](http://www.adefwebserver.com/dotnetnukehelp/dnn_showmethepages/) that will walk you through how to create super simple dnn module.

I suggest you to go to through [DNN Video Library](http://www.dotnetnuke.com/Resources/Video-Library.aspx) and get some basic knowledge on dnn module development.